# Us image src url in CSS background image url using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm novice at Javascript. I want to use an image src in CSS background image url using javascript.

For example,     `<img class="user-profile-box-img" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/portrait-young-man-using-mobile-phone-while-standing-outdoors_58466-16294.jpg"/>`

This is an image src to show image. I want to use the same image url in css **`background-image: url("")`**, so that I don't need to write twice the same url. How can I do it using javascript or jquery ?

To sum up, I'll just write image src once inside img tag, and it will automatically add in `background-image: url("");`

Code Example:

```css
.same-image-div {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 60px 15px!important;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(38, 70, 235, 0.4), rgba(38, 70, 235, 0.4)),    
url(" here I want the "user-profile-box-img" class image src url ");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.user-profile-box-img{
width: 50%;
margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="same-image-div">
<img class="user-profile-box-img" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/portrait-young-man-using-mobile-phone-while-standing-outdoors_58466-16294.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using JavaScript:

```
const img = document.querySelector('.user-profile-box-img');
const div = document.querySelector('.same-image-div');
div.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(rgba(38, 70, 235, 0.4), rgba(38, 70, 235, 0.4)), url(${img.src})`;
```

Here is one way to do it using jQuery:

```
const img = $('.user-profile-box-img');
const div = $('.same-image-div');
div.css('background-image', `linear-gradient(rgba(38, 70, 235, 0.4), rgba(38, 70, 235, 0.4)), url(${img.attr('src')})`);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the image src using jquery, you can use: `$('.user-profile-box-img').attr('src');`

then add this to **.same-image-div** class **background-image: url("")** property through Jquery or Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "move" src attribute to a CSS attribute of the same element, in jQuery you should do this (with a little element caching):

```
let element = $('img.user-profile-box-img');
element.css('background-image', 'url('+element.attr('src')+')');
```

Comment: Can you please give the the complete code with example ?

Comment: Just wrap this in <script></script> and add it to the page, preferably after page load. If your site has a JS file, you can add it there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an image src in CSS background image URL using javascript.
You have set the image using javascript simply like this :
element.style.background-image = "URL('img_tree.png')";

```
document.body.style.background-image = "URL('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1661956602139-ec64991b8b16?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2765&q=80')";
```

Comment: Raj, can't I use it once from <img src=""> ?????

Comment: don't want to add same url in my css background-image url(""), I want that I'll use it just <img src=""> attribute and automatically add on background image url.

Comment: yes you can use by creating element or using template

Comment: For example <img id="myImg" src=""/> document.getElementById("myImg").src = "hackanm.gif";